# How many jack studs do I need from each side for 6.5 feet patio door header?

Tags: doors, framing, door-frame

I'm installing a bigger patio door. Currently I have 3 jack studs from each side. To fit the door, I need to remove 1 of jack studs from each side. I think that according to a code I need 2. So I should be good. Any thoughts? Am I missing something? Just concerned why I have 3? Was there a reason?

Also looks like I have 1 of king studs from each side..  probably that's why they added 3 jack studs from each side?

This is 2 story house.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For a single story house(just have a roof above this) it seems over built.  Two or three floors above this, maybe not.

Comment: 2 story house... any advise to reinforce it?

Comment: See the tables at [IRC R602.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7). We need sufficient information to navigate these tables. If there's a sleeping room above the header, then that's interesting (30 psf live load instead of the 40 psf from the exterior wall table). If you decide to interpret the table yourself, then note how the number of plies to the header impacts the jack stud count.

Comment: @popham this is exterior wall, there is a non sleeping room above this door, and there is a small patio outside,  which leans on this wall 3 feet wider then the door opening from each side. I'm not 100% sure how to interpret this table. Could you please help? 

Comment: Do you have a gable roof? If so, then do you have trusses? Or do you have rafters that span the whole house without a vertical support from ridge beam down to a support wall or beam? Or rafters with support from below the ridge beam? What's your snow load? Do the ceiling joists span to a support beam or wall running under the roof ridge? What's the house width measured perpendicular to the wall?

Comment: Just snow load and house width along with pessimistic assumptions may prove that you can remove 1 jack stud from each side. Maybe best to start there before redrawing the construction drawings.

Comment: We are in texas, so not sure if snow load is required.  I remember maybe 2 inch of snow is the max.

Comment: The perpendicular width is 37 feet. The wall itself is 39. We have trusses.

Comment: @popham Hip roof.

Comment: Added a few pictures

Comment: Everything I seen in the code only requires 2 jack studs each side. Only when the span gets longer is 3 required.

Comment: @jack  I saw the same, I'm just concerned that I also have 1 king studs from each side instead of 2. I thought maybe that's why I have 3 jack studs instead. I'm not sure if I understand that correctly tho

Comment: How many 2 inch nominal width pieces are joined together to form your header?

Comment: @popham 2 pieces

Comment: See Table R602.7.5 under [IRC R602.7.5](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7.5) for your king stud count. The singles can be adequate depending on your wind load.

Comment: It looks like there's a shim at the left end of the header.  So it's more like 2.6 jack studs supporting the header at that end, and if you remove one it'll be 1.6.     If I'm seeing correctly what's at the left end of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gable roof assumption from Table R602.7(1) under [IRC R602.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7) will be conservative for your roof. Barely conservative for a door opening located at the wall's center. Increasingly conservative as the door opening moves away from center.

Footnote e of Table R602.7(1) prescribes the table's 30 psf snow load for your case with effectively zero snow load. This is especially conservative for areas with small wind loads. Apparently it remains conservative for areas with high wind loads.

The 36 ft house width column under Table R602.7(1) is close enough to your 37 ft house width to use. Assuming no roof load bearing supports apart from the perimeter walls is conservative, so the table's "Roof, ceiling and one center-bearing floor" row provides conservative header sizes. Unfortunately, for headers built up from 2 pieces, the table's header span lengths only go up to 5'-8" with 2 jack studs at each end. Your header with 2 jack studs on each side has a span of 6'-0". Unfortunately you can't look at longer spans built up from 3 pieces, because the additional piece dilutes the bearing pressure on top of the jack studs.

The roof contributes

2A(30psf+10psf) / [A(40psf+10psf)+2A(30psf+10psf)] = 60%

of the load, so (given your hip roof) I would call 2 jack studs "good enough" if it's well away from the wall's center. That little roof from the other side makes me a little uneasy, though.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I've uploaded another picture with the roof and door location. Consider that, do you think is it safe to keep 1 king and 2 jacks? (remove 3rd jack from each side)

Comment: or do you think that it make sense to reinforce it somehow?

Comment: @Rainmaker, I read that single king stud as evidence of low wind loads. Conversely, I read the hip roof itself as evidence of high wind loads (I'm under a hip roof right now, though, without the high wind). Low wind? I'd call it good enough. High wind makes me uneasy with that canopy outside. 80" / 16" = 5 spaces and therefore 4 wall studs under a 6'-8" length of wall. Admittedly the bearing area is 3" wide instead of the wall's 3-1/2" wide bearing area, but I think the 2 studs are good.

Comment: @Rainmaker, and a header span for the code is measured from inside of jack stud to inside of jack stud. I've been subtracting 6" from your 6'-6" in my mind when comparing against the 5'-8".

Comment: Just read about my area. And we are in severe wind factor.

Comment: What can I do to reinforce it?

Comment: I can add 1 king from each side. Will it help?

Comment: I can add 1 king from the right side, but I think it's not possible from the left because of electrical wiring coming out from ceiling in that area

Comment: I can replace 2×4 from the left with 1×4 if that will make any difference  :)

Comment: @Rainmaker, based on the 6'-8" with 4 studs reasoning, I think the 2 pairs of jack studs are fine against buckling. That leaves bearing as the only questionable limit state. That IRC table uses the weakest values of the #2 softwood species. Hem-Fir is the weakest in bearing, where I compute the maximum length for two jack studs as 71.8". For the next weakest softwood it's 75.5".

Comment: @Rainmaker, I would verify for sure that you need an extra king stud. How sure are you? If it's needed, it's purpose is to resist horizontal wind load on the face of that wall.